# Laravel Livewire - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: laravel-valet, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel Valet in my development environment and I came across this error today when sending a post request with Livewire.

**~/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log**:

```
2020/05/17 10:44:27 [error] 3611#0: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /livewire/message/autocomplete.users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/macuser/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "blog.test", referrer: "http://blog.test/dashboard"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it, change the following config files in your environment:

1. Create file `~/.config/valet/Nginx/all.conf`

```
proxy_buffer_size   4096k;
proxy_buffers   128 4096k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   4096k;
```

2. Append to file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 4096k;
fastcgi_buffers 128 4096k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 4096k;
```

After that, `valet restart`.

The solution was originally posted by [colbyalbo](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/890).